# How to store JPEG file path from internal storage to SQLite database & what data type to store it as?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, jpeg, internal-storage

I am trying to display images from my internal storage onto my recycler view, I have made the image resources into Bitmaps using the `convertToBitmap ()` and saved them as jpeg files in shared storage using the `storeToFile ()` & `saveBitmap ()`.

However, I would like to store the jpeg file paths into my SQLite database and retrieve them in the recycler view adapter. The problem is I don't know how I would store jpeg file paths in SQLite database & what data type I would use for the columns.

***Method for converting resource to bitmap:***

```
public void convertToBitmap () {
    faan = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.faan);
}
```

***Method for storing bitmap in shared storage as JPG:***

```
public void saveBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
    File filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (filePath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Items/");

    dir.mkdir();

    File file = new File (dir, name + ".jpg");

    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
}

public void storeToFile () {
    saveBitmap(faan,"Faan");
}
```

Comment: Why would you copy all those file from resources to file system?

Comment: If you want to use the images in a recycler view then you can directly load them from resources.

Comment: `The problem is I don't know how I would store jpeg file paths in SQLite database & what data type I would use for the columns.`. To answer your question: a file path is just the value of a string.

Comment: @blackapps so then i could store the filepaths into the sqlite I was told this was the best method to store images to sqlite. I've tried storing the bitmaps as bytes in the database but I ran into trouble with the cursor when retrieving those bytes as the size was too big.

Comment: @blackapps i tried doing this at first but there was problems storing the id resources of each image into the sqlite database.

Comment: What problem exactly! Resource id's are just integers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:
If you have a few images that belong to the same objects, you could save the paths as in a String column comma separated ("first_path, second_path, third_path, ...")

When you retrieve that value you could use myString.split(",") to get the paths in a String array

If each image belongs to a different object you have to create a String column for the path, but each path would be in a different row belonging to the corresponding object in the database.